# IOS: sound in a scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, mp3

I have this code:

```
- (void) setAudioScroll{
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                  @"scroll1.mp3"];
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
soundScroll = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
[soundScroll prepareToPlay]; 

}

- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


    [soundScroll play];
}
```

Then I want to make a sound when scrollview scroll. but when I scroll it I see that don't work fine because when it call the mp3 sound it stop its scroll for a short time. Can I use a separated thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Is called many times during a single scroll, at very short time intervals, you don't want to be calling `[soundScroll play];` every time this callback occurs, instead use this callback

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

so that the sound is played once when the scrolling starts, or either of these

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

if you want the sound the play after the user scrolls. If you want a short sound to be looping continuously through the scroll you can set the `AVAudioPlayer` numberOfLoops property to a negative value so that it loops indefinately, then stop it when the scrolling stops.

Comment: I understand that you tell me, but my mp3 is a single "clip", it takes less than a second...and then I call mp3 many time

Comment: Put an NSLog in scrollViewDidScroll, you'll see at what rate it's called during scrolling. What you can do is set the AVAudioPlayer numberOfLoops property to a negative value so that it loops indefinately, then stop it when the scrolling stops.